# can an app run on android and ios

Tags: android, ios

Want to create an app which can run on both ios and android without modifications.
Cider (http://engineering.columbia.edu/sync-columbia-engineering-team-first-run-ios-apps-android-platform)
seems to be promising. But couldn't find any examples.

Are there any other means of getting this to work? We don't want to maintain 2 codebases for the same app for ios and android.

Comment: use phone gap or cordova or titanium or else use any Hybrid method, it s easy to use

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to write an app for both Android and iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957168/best-way-to-write-an-app-for-both-android-and-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am used the following steps to convert

http://www.apportable.com/    please refer this link.Using this sdk we can

directly convert  `Xcode project` into `Android project`.

I tested this sdk.It is give amazing output.

It is only need four steps for converting.

this is for your reference , in before i never used ,bz i don't knw `JAVA`.if u need this convert `Android` to `iOS` use this link

http://www.androidcentral.com/google-develops-tool-translate-java-ios-friendly-objective-c-code

Comment: Please don't abuse `Code formatting` for things that are not pieces of code. Java is a programming language, and Android and iOS are OS. **Both are not pieces of code.**

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `Apache Cordova`. Supports almost any platform you like and is open source.
http://cordova.apache.org/

Other option would be `Xamarin`. Has a commercial license for both platforms.
http://xamarin.com/

Answer (score 1):

ok try to develop app in `phonegap(cordova)` by using `html`,`css` and `JavaScript` programming language

Answer (score 0):

The link u provided is an on going research,it will take more than 3-4 yrs before it can come in market,However u can use the existing technologies like

1. phonegap
2. titanium .... to do what u want

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), you will have one app for platforms other than Android and iOS also.

> PhoneGap is a mobile development framework produced by Nitobi, purchased by Adobe Systems in 2011.[3][4] It enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS3, instead of device-specific languages such as Objective-C.[5] It enables wrapping up of HTML, CSS and Javascript code depending upon the platform of the device. It extends the features of HTML and Javascript to work with the device. The resulting applications are hybrid, meaning that they are neither truly Mobile native application native (because all layout rendering is done via web views instead of the platform's native UI framework) nor purely web-based (because they are not just web apps, but are packaged as apps for distribution and have access to native device APIs). From version 1.9 onward it is even possible to freely mix native and hybrid code snippets.